# Could not load file or assembly [System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll]

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm using Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.276; Windows 2k3.

After reset IIS some days. This error occurs again.

I did not find a complete solution for below error:

```
Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[NotImplementedException: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))]
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +9587987
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +43
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +172
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +43
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +828
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +327
```

Please let me know a complete solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

while running the project from visual studio force the platform target as 32 bit using following steps:

```
->Right click on Project
->Select Properties
->Goto Build Options
->Change  "Platform Target" from "ANY CPU" to "X86"
```

now run the Project.